# Setting bolts to read from specific streams of other bolts in trident topology

Tags: apache-storm, trident, apache-storm-topology

I am trying to write a TridentTopology, which has multiple bolts. Now I want to make one bolt register to other bolts specific stream as shown below.

```
TridentTopologyBuilder tridentTopologyBuilder = new TridentTopologyBuilder();
FixedBatchSpout spout = new FixedBatchSpout(new Fields("sentence"), 2,
                                            new Values("the cow jumped over the moon"),
                                            new Values("the man went to the store and bought some candy"),
                                            new Values("four score and seven years ago"),
                                            new Values("how many apples can you eat"));

tridentTopologyBuilder.setSpout("tridentSpout", "spoutStream", "spoutId", spout, 2, "spoutBatch");
Map<String, String> batchGroups = new HashMap<>();
batchGroups.put("boltStream", "boltBatch");
tridentTopologyBuilder.setBolt("tridentBolt", new TridentTestBolt(), 1, Sets.newHashSet("spoutBatch"), batchGroups).shuffleGrouping("tridentSpout", "spoutStream");

tridentTopologyBuilder.setBolt("tridentBolt2", new TridentTestBolt2(), 1, new HashSet<>(), batchGroups).shuffleGrouping("tridentBolt", "boltStream");

LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
Config config = new Config();
config.setDebug(true);
cluster.submitTopology("TridentTopology", config, tridentTopologyBuilder.buildTopology(new HashMap<>()));
```

I am getting following exception:

```
Error: InvalidTopologyException(msg:Component: [tridentBolt2] subscribes from non-existent stream: [$coord-boltBatch] of component [tridentBolt])
```

Also declared stream using the declareStream method of OutputFieldsDeclarer

```
@Override
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    declarer.declareStream("boltStream", new Fields("sentence"));
}
```

Also registering to other bolts specific stream works in normal topology. The issue is with Trident topology. Also What are we supposed to pass for `batchGroups`.

Comment: How do `TridentTestBolt` and `TridentTestBolt2` look like?